# In my local server I lost .state file but .statefile.backup is in place . So now how to get back .statefile

Tags: terraform

''
In my local server I lost .state file but  .statefile.backup is in place . So now how to get back .statefile. When I do terraform apply its recreating infra again I don't want
''

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you removed your `.state` file.
You can use .state.backup to get back to your last applied state. The backup file is literally your previous state file. Simply copy-and-rename/move (I would recommend coping just in case) it like this:

```
cp terraform.tfstate.backup terraform.tfstate
```

You have your statefile back in place.

Run terraform plan to asses how much resources you're missing after removing your latest statefile version.
You can [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html) resources instead of recreating them if needed.